# Obtaining $95$ CI of an estimate

Tags: statistics

You have been tasked with estimating the average grade of students. All students in a province is your target population. It is known that the size of your target population is $80000.$ There are $26400$ "$A$" students of these employees with those having an average grade of $95%$ per semester. Then you are able to collect information from a simple random sample of $100$ of those students not on the "$A$" list. The mean grade in those sampled is $70%$ per semester, with a standard deviation of $5.$

Give an estimate of the average grade of all students in the province. Accompany a $95%$ CI for the estimate.

The first part is simply getting the weighted average $$0.95 (26400/80000) + 0.7 ((80000-264000)/80000) = 0.7825.$$

But then, for the second part how should I obtain the $95$ CI?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the number of A students, and let $b$ the number of other students. Let random variable $X$ be the average of the grades of a randomly selected (with replacement) sample of $100$ other students. The mean of $X$ is $0.70$ and the variance of $X$ is $\frac{(0.05)^2}{100}$.

The average grade of the students in the province is, by an argument essentially identical to yours, equal to $\frac{a}{a+b}(0.95)+\frac{b}{a+b}X$. The variance of this is $\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^2$ times the variance of $X$.

Now if we assume approximate normality of $X$ we have all the information required to calculate a $95\%$ confidence interval.

Comment: Sorry. But I am a bit confused. Why are we using the variance to calculate the 95% CI?

Comment: We  always use the variance $\sigma^2$ in calculations with a normal, or an approximately normal. Of course what goes into the formula is the square root of the variance. But generally we must compute the variance  before finding the standard deviation.

Comment: Am I correct to assume N as 80000 to calculate the CI with 1.96 (sqrt(variance of average)/sqrt(N))

Comment: In the "general" answer I wrote, $a+b=800000$.  And for the CI, you will be using $0.7825\pm 1.96\sigma$, where I have given instructions for computing $\sigma$. The answer above was basically all about computing $\sigma$.